# occi segmentation fault error

Tags: c++, oracle, oracle10g, segmentation-fault, occi

I am using [OCCI](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/oci/index-090820.html) to connect Oracle and C++. When i try to access all the records in the table(which has 10 records), the following code snippet displays only 4 records from the table and the program ends with "segmentation fault" message.

## Table Employee

```
Name         Null?    Type
 ------------ -------- ---------------
 ID           NOT NULL NUMBER(6)
 NAME         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
 AGE          NOT NULL NUMBER(3)
 SALARY       NOT NULL NUMBER(6)
 VA                    NUMBER(8,2)
```

## Code

```
    #include<occi.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace oracle::occi;
using namespace std;


int main ()
{
   Environment *env;
   Connection *conn;
   string userName ;
   string password ;
   string database ;

   userName="e224312";
   password="ipgdMCicy";
   database="oraconn";

   cout << "OCCI Demo" << endl;

   env=Environment::createEnvironment(Environment::DEFAULT);
   conn=env->createConnection(userName,password,database);

   cout << "OCCI Environment  and Connection Created " << endl;

   int idx=0;
   int ch;
   int c1;
   string c2;

   int c3;  

   Statement *stmt = conn->createStatement("SELECT * FROM employee");
   cout << "Selecting Records from Table " << endl;
   ResultSet *rs = stmt->executeQuery();

   while(rs->next()){
    c1 = rs->getInt(1);
    c2 = rs->getString(2);
    c3 = rs->getInt(3); 
    cout <<"ID   :" << c1 << endl;
    cout <<"Name :" << c2 << endl;
    cout <<"Age  :" << c3 << endl;
   }
   cout << "Terminating the Connection and The Environment" << endl;
   env->terminateConnection(conn);
   Environment::terminateEnvironment(env);

   cout << "Normal End" << endl;
}
```

I am using unix g++ compiler. What is the reason for this abrupt end of the execution and how can I correct it?

## GDP Stack Trace

```
 ~/project/test> gdb testgdb
GNU gdb Fedora (6.8-37.el5)
Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i386-redhat-linux-gnu"...
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/518377/project/test/testgdb
warning: .dynamic section for "/lib/libm.so.6" is not at the expected address
warning: difference appears to be caused by prelink, adjusting expectations
warning: .dynamic section for "/lib/libc.so.6" is not at the expected address
warning: difference appears to be caused by prelink, adjusting expectations
warning: .dynamic section for "/usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.4/client/lib/libnnz10.so" is not at the expected address
warning: difference appears to be caused by prelink, adjusting expectations
warning: .dynamic section for "/lib/libdl.so.2" is not at the expected address
warning: difference appears to be caused by prelink, adjusting expectations
warning: .dynamic section for "/lib/libpthread.so.0" is not at the expected address
warning: difference appears to be caused by prelink, adjusting expectations
warning: .dynamic section for "/lib/libnsl.so.1" is not at the expected address
warning: difference appears to be caused by prelink, adjusting expectations
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
OCCI Demo
[New Thread 0xb7fe08e0 (LWP 32385)]
OCCI Environment  and Connection Created
Selecting Records from Table
Emp Id   :7
Emp Name :Arun
Age      :23
Emp Id   :8
Emp Name :Babu
Age      :25
Emp Id   :9
Emp Name :Catherine
Age      :21
Emp Id   :10
Emp Name :Dinesh
Age      :20

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x001a09cc in free () from /lib/libc.so.6
```

Comment: Are you sure, that ` employee` table has 3 fields and they are int-string-int?

Comment: What is the definition of table employee? What are c1, c2 and c3?

Comment: You should specify each of the columns, in order, in your `SELECT` statement.  And that statement handle probably needs closing before disconnecting too, I'll wager.  This isn't your issue though.

Comment: How does the initialization/declaration of env/conn look like?

Comment: +1 trojanfoe, it is always better to explicit specify the column names to be sure that you get the values in the order you expect them to come.

Comment: Question edited with table structure and full code.

Comment: Probably time to get `gdb` out to find where it crashes.  Post the stacktrace.

Comment: @trojanfoe: how to do it with gdb?

Comment: You can run the program like this: `$ gdb myprog` and then, when inside gdb, start it with: `r arg1 arg2` or simply `r`.

Comment: @trojanfoe : I have updated. Please find the stack trace in the question.

Comment: OK, to get the stacktrace type `where` when it crashes.  Also ensure you compile with debug info by using the `-g` compiler flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the Problem with g++ compiler. It worked when i used gcc compiler.